# How to draw an unknown number of charts using charts.js (or google charts) with a loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js

I'm not really after code but got myself into a loop (no pun). I'm hoping that by the time I write this down, I'll work it out.

I'm trying to think how to draw a number of charts to show a student's grade and the average grade. A student will have have a number of grades which will change over time. I'm trying to work out how to do this.

I've used google charts before and that's fine the issue is how to create and display a number of charts where the number required is unknown.

The data will be in the database and so I use Ajax requests to return JSON data for the grade (student grade, average, and labels). when I know how many charts to produce it's fine.

I think I need to do something like (all in javascript?)

1. Query to return the number of grades -AJax so useable in Javascript
2. Use above query to create a loop to process all grades
3. Within loop  -use Ajax to produce data for each chart - query=user and grade
4. within loop - create chart using JS library like charts.js or google charts
5. Within loop - create appropriate  to attach chart to

step 3 is where I'm stuck: I'm struggling as in the case I don't know how many grades to query and what parameters to use e.g. Ajax query ..../userid/grade-title

In this case, it's unknown until I start looking for the data.

Has anyone done similar? Do you just use Javascript to render all the s required to display charts? Do I initially build an array of grades to query -not just the count of grades to display?

I'm writing this here as it usually helps and as I type I think I've worked it out but just now wondering if anyone has any other suggestions. Just a list of steps is fine.

Comment: Sounds like you need a callback from your ajax request.

Comment: In order to approach this in a structured way, make a separate function for every of the identified steps that only carries out this specific task and returns the result. I.e. #1 make Ajax request, return array (this can be reused in #3). #2 Accept array, process grades, return processed array. #4 accept chart data, draw chart. And so on. Each function should do the right thing independently when called with test data.

Comment: It's hard to tell how #3 should look like without seeing any data or sample code. On top of that, the overall question scope is too large. If you only struggle with #3, trim your question down so that it only is about #3. Provide the relevant data and the code you have so far.

Comment: Hi
I've not written any code for this yet as I'm trying to work out just generally how to process it. Thanks for the tips. I think as you say the bit I was struggling with was that I need an array to hold the details of the grades to add to Ajax requests in the loop. A count wasn't enough.